# Issue calling a method of class using this when function is called using super

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
class Dog {
  bark () {
    console.log(`Dog.bark`)
  }
  callMyBark () {
    // how do I have this function use the bark above and not Pug.bark?
    this.bark()
  }
}

class Pug extends Dog {
  bark () {
    console.log(`Pug.bark`)
  }
  callMyBark () {
    super.callMyBark()
  }
}

let pug = new Pug()

pug.callMyBark()
```

The above code logs `Pug.bark` and the expected behavior is to log `Dog.bark`. How can I have the `Dog.callMyBark` method run `Dog.bark` instead?

Comment: The whole point of calling methods dynamically is allowing them to be overwritten?

Comment: If you don't want `bark` to be overriden in standard OO class fashion, perhaps you should reconsider how you are calling the function? Can you move it off the class entirely as a helper, then call the helper from both places instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, but I think the best is to call the `super` method or just not override at all:

```
class Pug extends Dog {
  bark () {
    super.bark(); // or omit the method entirely
  }

  callMyBark () {
    super.callMyBark()
  }
}
```

Obviously that doesn't take into account where you're calling from, which seems to be how you want to decide.

Bear in mind that choosing the method based on caller like that is something of an antipattern in most OO languages and much work has been done to avoid accidentally doing that (it was a problem in C++, which is part of why later languages default to virtual dispatch).

I would strongly suggest making the function `static` or some detached helper if you really need to and calling it directly:

```
class Dog {
  static bark() {
    console.log(`Dog.bark`)
  }

  callMyBark () {
    // how do I have this function use the bark above and not Pug.bark?
    Dog.bark()
  }
}
```

If you need `this` within the function, you can pass an instance to the helper, or you can call through the prototype (or the instance's prototype chain):

```
class Dog {
  bark() {
    console.log(`Dog.bark`)
  }

  callMyBark () {
    // how do I have this function use the bark above and not Pug.bark?
    Dog.prototype.bark.call(this);
  }
}
```

There is no pretty solution, likely because this can typically be avoided.

Comment: In the last instance, you could use `super.bark.call(this)` instead of explicitly calling out the `Dog` class